# Distribute integers for tag cloud weighting

Tags: c#, algorithm, distribution, statistics

I have a list of words that I want to display in a web page as a tag cloud. Each word has a corresponding 'weight' which determines how big the word should appear in the tag cloud.

Let's say that this array contains the number of times each word has been used to tag a document and I want to use these values as the weighting for each word:

```
int [] ints = new int[] { 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1000};
```

I want the range of weightings to be within a specified range such that the rendering code has a predictable set of numbers to deal with however I don't want to simply normalize these integers because then all but the last will be essentially zero.

If this were to happen then there'd be a single item in the tag cloud that would be very big and all the other tags would be tiny. I'm looking for a way of squeezing all the of the integers into a limited range whilst preserving a degree of diversity.

So how can I transform the set such that the final large value doesn't make the others insignificant?

Comment: This isn't clear.  What do you want to do with these values?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you might consider using [Logarithmic scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_scale) before normalizing your integers.

Comment: Most likely approach here would be to normalize the logs

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Please see question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use logarithms to pre-process the data and bring down the scale of the numbers. Choose the base to the logarithm based on the data values. For the purpose of a tag cloud, using log to base 2 would be most ideal in my opinion. Once you have found the log, normalize the resulting numbers.

Comment: Seems quite hard to normalize them afterwards because whatever the base, log of one is zero.

Comment: @IanWarburton: Yes, by definition, log 1 would always be 0, for any base. To overcome this, you can add 1 to all numbers once you take log and then normalize them.

Comment: @IanWarburton You can also have fractional bases, so if base 2 does not give you a satisfactory distribution, then try smaller numbers that lie between 1 and 2 as the base.